# vbscript sendkeys for shift+Break

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft, sendkeys

I'm not able to preform Shift+Break using sendkeys.

```
mysendkeys.SendKeys "+{BREAK}"
```

Where in below send keys are working

```
mysendkeys.SendKeys "+{7}" //to enter &
```

Where in below send keys are working

```
Dim mysendkeys        
Set mysendkeys = CreateObject("WScript.shell")  

mysendkeys.SendKeys "+{7}" //to enter &
mysendkeys.SendKeys "+{BREAK}" // not preforming
```

I'm not able to perform shift+Break using send keys in uft. I tried with settings regfile assigning keyboard functions as well.
Manually i am able to perform this action .